# Why does SHAPE.SDO_ORDINATES(1) work in PL/SQL, but not in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, attributes, oracle18c, oracle-spatial

Oracle 18c:

I can extract the startpoint X coordinate from an SDO_GEOMETRY using `SHAPE.SDO_ORDINATES(1)` in a custom PL/SQL function:

```
with 
function startpoint_x(shape in sdo_geometry) return number 
is
begin
  return 
  shape.sdo_ordinates(1); 
end;

select
  startpoint_x(shape) as startpoint_x
from
  (select sdo_geometry('linestring(1 2, 3 4, 5 6)') as shape 
   from dual)

STARTPOINT_X
------------
           1
```

But if I try do that purely in an SQL query, I get an error:

```
select
  (shape).sdo_ordinates(1) as startpoint_x
from
  (select sdo_geometry('linestring(1 2, 3 4, 5 6)') as shape 
   from dual)

ORA-00904: "MDSYS"."SDO_GEOMETRY"."SDO_ORDINATES": invalid identifier
```

For what it's worth, if I were to remove the (1) and instead select the entire `sdo_ordinates` attribute, then that would work:

```
select
  (shape).sdo_ordinates as ordinates 
from
  (select sdo_geometry('linestring(1 2, 3 4, 5 6)') as shape 
   from dual)

ORDINATES
------------------------
SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(1, 2)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=38d5b18e84128afb886810bdbec7a982)

But of course, that's not what I want. I want to get the startpoint X coordinate as a number.

Why does `SHAPE.SDO_ORDINATES(1)` work in PL/SQL, but not in an SQL query?

---

Somewhat related: [Get X & Y coordinates from GEOM_SEGMENT_START_PT()](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4499536/get-x-y-coordinates-from-geom-segment-start-pt#latest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does `SHAPE.SDO_ORDINATES(1)` work in PL/SQL, but not in an SQL query?

Because the syntax of extracting collection elements by index is not supported in SQL. It is not just SDO objects but any collection:

```sql
SELECT SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('a', 'b', 'c')(1) FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ORA-03001: unimplemented feature
> ```

and:

```sql
SELECT l.list(1)
FROM   (SELECT SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('a', 'b', 'c') AS list FROM DUAL) l;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ORA-00904: "L"."LIST": invalid identifier
> ```

*(Which, I think means that it is trying to parse it as a function but the error message is less helpful/obvious than the previous one.)*

---

There are methods of getting the value but it is more complicated as you need to dereference the entire collection using a table collection expression and then filter to get the desired row:

```sql
SELECT (
         SELECT COLUMN_VALUE
         FROM   TABLE(s.shape.sdo_ordinates)
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       ) as startpoint_x
FROM  (
  select sdo_geometry('linestring(1 2, 3 4, 5 6)') as shape from dual
) s
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=781ec9cd4d462b114e6182df78d13d2a)*

Comment: Thanks! FYI, I submitted an idea to Oracle: [Support extracting collection elements by index in SQL](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4499553/support-extracting-collection-elements-by-index-in-sql/p1?new=1). Hopefully that idea is sensible?

Comment: You might find this technique interesting: `json_value((shape).Get_GeoJson(),'$.coordinates[0][0]')`. https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/comment/16840191/#Comment_16840191

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that varrays and table collections have to be treated as tables, and SQL (3) doesn't support them in native SQL.

Answer (score 0):

See if such a workaround helps ...

This is what you have and it works:

```
SQL> select
  2    (shape).sdo_ordinates as ordinates
  3  from
  4    (select sdo_geometry('linestring(1 2, 3 4, 5 6)') as shape
  5     from dual);

ORDINATES
------------------------------------------------------------
SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

This is what you tried, but it doesn't work:

```
SQL> select
  2    (shape).sdo_ordinates(1) as startpoint_x
  3  from
  4    (select sdo_geometry('linestring(1 2, 3 4, 5 6)') as shape
  5     from dual);
  (shape).sdo_ordinates(1) as startpoint_x
                       *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: "MDSYS"."SDO_GEOMETRY"."SDO_ORDINATES": invalid identifier
```

And this is a **workaround**:

```
SQL> select
  2    sdo_geom.sdo_min_mbr_ordinate(shape, 1) as startpoint_x
  3  from
  4    (select sdo_geometry('linestring(1 2, 3 4, 5 6)') as shape
  5     from dual);

STARTPOINT_X
------------
           1

SQL>
```

Comment: I think it might just be a coincidence that MBR (minimum bounding rectangle) works in this case, for this test data. I suspect it wouldn’t provide the right results for real-world geometries.