# Why does CROSS JOIN LATERAL break up array's SDO_GEOMETRY object into individual attributes?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle18c, oracle-spatial, lateral-join

*Oracle 18c:*

I have mapping software that has a limitation where it can only handle a single geometry column per table. If there are multiple geometry columns in a given table, then it will throw an error.

So, I want to find a way to add an additional geometry column to a table, but store it as a datatype that the mapping software doesn't recognize — so it will ignore that column (TBD).

One idea is to store an SDO_GEOMETRY as an [SDO_GEOMETRY_ARRAY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72590504/5576771) datatype, since the software wouldn't recognize SDO_GEOMETRY_ARRAY. I would always only store a single geometry in the array.

Similar to this:

```
with data (geom_array) as (
select sdo_geometry_array(sdo_geometry('point(10 20)')) from dual union all
select sdo_geometry_array(sdo_geometry('point(30 40)')) from dual union all
select sdo_geometry_array(sdo_geometry('point(50 60)')) from dual
)
select geom_array from data

GEOM_ARRAY (SQL Developer)
----------------------------------------------
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY_ARRAY([MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY])
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY_ARRAY([MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY])
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY_ARRAY([MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY])
```

---

Unsurprisingly, when I select from the array, it returns the entire array, not the SDO_GEOMETRY (even though there's only a single value in the array).

So, I want to find an ***easy/succinct*** way to extract the SDO_GEOMETRY from the array.

I could use a custom function, which works as expected:

```
with 
function get_geom_from_array(geom_array sdo_geometry_array) return sdo_geometry is
begin
    return geom_array(1);
end;    
data (geom_array) as (
select sdo_geometry_array(sdo_geometry('point(10 20)')) from dual union all
select sdo_geometry_array(sdo_geometry('point(30 40)')) from dual union all
select sdo_geometry_array(sdo_geometry('point(50 60)')) from dual
)
select
    get_geom_from_array(geom_array)
from   
    data

SDO_GEOM
---------------
[MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY]
[MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY]
[MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY]
```

Or I could use a [CROSS JOIN LATERAL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72583361/5576771):

```
select
    v.*
from   
    data d
cross join lateral (
    select sdo_geometry(sdo_gtype, sdo_srid, sdo_point, sdo_elem_info, sdo_ordinates) as sdo_geom
    from   table(d.sdo_array)
    ) v

SDO_GEOM
---------------
[MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY]
[MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY]
[MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY]
```

That CROSS JOIN LATERAL works, but I don't understand why it splits the SDO_GEOMETRY into it's attribute components:

```
select
    v.*
from   
    data d
cross join lateral (
    select *
    from   table(d.sdo_array)
    ) v

SDO_GTYPE SDO_SRID SDO_POINT              SDO_ELEM_INFO SDO_ORDINATES
--------- -------- ---------------------- ------------- -------------
     2001     null [MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE]          null          null
     2001     null [MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE]          null          null
     2001     null [MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE]          null          null
```

As such, I need to reconstruct the geometry from those attributes, like this: `sdo_geometry(sdo_gtype, sdo_srid, sdo_point, sdo_elem_info, sdo_ordinates)`.

Reconstructing the SDO_GEOMETRY is slightly inconvenient. But also, I want to understand why that happens in the CROSS JOIN LATERAL, but not in the custom function.

---

**Question:**

Why does the CROSS JOIN LATERAL break up the array's SDO_GEOMETRY object into individual attributes? (but the function doesn't)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` break up the array's `SDO_GEOMETRY` object into individual attributes? (but the function doesn't)

`CROSS JOIN LATERAL` is treating the table collection expression as if it is an object-derived table (which it effectively is) and uses each object of the collection to form a row of a table and then the columns are the attributes of the object.

The function is returning a single object into one column of one row. They are very different operations.

---

If you want to get the objects that comprise each row from the table collection expression then use the [`VALUE` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions209.htm):

```sql
SELECT v.obj
FROM   data d
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT VALUE(t) AS obj
         FROM   TABLE(d.sdo_array) t
       ) v
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=7e6d5478ac9ee193abacdbbca247be46)*

Comment: Thanks. Is an object-derived table different from a nested table?

Comment: @User1974 Yes, an object-derived table is a table where each row is an object (created with `CREATE TABLE table_name OF object_type` and you do not have to declare the columns as they are just the object's attributes) whereas a nested table is a nested table collection type stored "within" a table.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there are any other names for "object-derived tables"? I tried googling that term, but there weren't many results: https://www.google.com/search?q=oracle+%22object-derived+table%22

Comment: @User1974 [Object Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14260/adobjint.htm) or an [Object Relational Database (Management System)](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1545206281987)