# Extract varray element by index number using custom type's member function

Tags: sql, oracle, member-functions, oracle18c, oracle-spatial

*Oracle 18c:*

I've created a user-defined type and a member function that work ask expected.

The member function returns an `mdsys.sdo_ordinate_array` such as `MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60)`.

```
create type my_sdo_geom_type as object ( 
  shape sdo_geometry, 
  member function GetOrdinates(self in my_sdo_geom_type) 
  return mdsys.sdo_ordinate_array deterministic) 
/ 
create or replace type body my_sdo_geom_type as 
  member function GetOrdinates(self in my_sdo_geom_type) 
  return mdsys.sdo_ordinate_array is 
    begin 
       return shape.sdo_ordinates; 
    end; 
end; 
/ 
create table lines (my_sdo_geom_col my_sdo_geom_type);
insert into lines (my_sdo_geom_col) values (my_sdo_geom_type(sdo_geometry('linestring(10 20, 30 40, 50 60)')));

select
  (my_sdo_geom_col).GetOrdinates()
from
  lines

Result:
MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=17edda65f7b3b8ec9d690675e271e030)

---

That member function works, but what I actually want to do is return a specific ordinate using the ordinate index number, instead of returning the entire varray.

Like this:

```
select
  (my_sdo_geom_col).GetOrdinates(1)  <-- I used (1) instead of ()
from
  lines

Error:
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GETORDINATES'

Desired result:
10
```

In a related post, we said:

> ...the syntax of extracting collection elements by index is not supported in SQL.
>
> [Why does SHAPE.SDO_ORDINATES(1) work in PL/SQL, but not in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72571112/5576771)

But, if I understand correctly, that statement refers to using an object attribute, not a member function.

---

**Question:**

Is there a way to extract a varray element by index number using the custom type's member function?

I'm aware there are other ways of getting a geometry's ordinates. I'm doing this as a learning exercise/experiment, as it relates to some ideas I've submitted to Oracle:

- Oracle Spatial Idea: [Add a SDO_ORDINATES member function (for extracting collection elements by index)](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4499916/idea-add-a-sdo-ordinates-member-function-for-extracting-collection-elements-by-index)
- Oracle Idea: [Support extracting collection elements by index in SQL](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4499553/support-extracting-collection-elements-by-index-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the ordinate value from the array in the PL/SQL scope (within the member function) rather than returning the entire array to the SQL scope and trying to access the ordinate from there (which does not work):

```sql
CREATE TYPE my_sdo_geom_type AS OBJECT( 
  shape SDO_GEOMETRY, 

  MEMBER FUNCTION GetOrdinates(
    self IN my_sdo_geom_type,
    idx  IN NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER
) 
/ 

CREATE TYPE BODY my_sdo_geom_type AS
  MEMBER FUNCTION GetOrdinates(
    self IN my_sdo_geom_type,
    idx  IN NUMBER
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN 
    return shape.sdo_ordinates(idx);
  END;
END;
/
```

Then you can use it in the query:

```sql
select (my_sdo_geom_col).GetOrdinates(3)
from   lines
```

Outputs:

> | (MY_SDO_GEOM_COL).GETORDINATES(3) |
> | --- |
> | 30 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=fcddcaefb8ff89e0dd23e4b1cced9c77)*